# Deleted Project from Package Explorer, but cannot import it because it is still in the workspace

Tags: eclipse, workspace

A few months ago I had a whole bunch of projects in my `Package Explorer` which I didn't think that I would ever use. So I deleted them to make some more room. I am still using the same workspace from back then, and the projects I deleted actually still exist in the `/workspace` directory.

This is a picture of my Eclipse window when I try to Import the project.[image]

This is a picture of my `workspace` directory:

[image]

I'm assuming I could move the project and then re-import it, but is there no cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: I don'y have Eclipse on this computer, so I'm not putting this as an answer but... what happens if you uncheck `Copy Projects into Workspace`?

Comment: I ended up just moving it out of my `/workspace` directory and then Importing it. Looking back now, this definitely could have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In future, as mentioned [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-42b.htm) be sure to select the **Also delete contents under ...** option while deleting a project:

[image: 1]